# Baffling Index-Out-Of-Bounds

Tags: c#, matrix, multidimensional-array

There a section in my code where I need to invert a matrix. That can only reasonably be done on a square matrix, in this case a 3x3 square matrix. The tool I'm using to invert the matrix kept saying that my array wasn't a proper square.

So I did a little test:

```
double[,] x = new double[3, 3];

MessageBox.Show(x.GetLength(0).ToString());
MessageBox.Show(x.GetLength(1).ToString());
MessageBox.Show(x.GetLength(2).ToString());
```

First one comes up as "3". Second one comes up as "3". Third one comes up as an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. Am I just overlooking something extremely obvious or... is this a little weird?

(Note: This is code from C# using .Net 2.0)

Comment: All residents of Flatland know that the mere notion of a third dimension is quite absurd.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**You only have an array with two dimensions.** Why would you expect asking for the size of the third dimensions to give you a valid result?

The `Array.GetLength()` method return the number of elements in the specified dimension of the Array. In your case:

```
x.GetLength(2).ToString();   // asking for size of third dimension
```

you're asking a 2-dimensional array what the size of it's third dimension is. The result is an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. This is the expected behavior.

In your code example, it looks like you may be confusing the size of each stated dimension, with the *number of dimensions.* Here are some examples of rectangular arrays of different dimensions:

```
var d1 = new int[5];     // one dimensional array, containing 5 elements
var d2 = new int[3,3];   // two-dimensional 3x3 element array
var d3 = new int[2,2,2]; // three-dimension array of 2x2x2 elements
var d4 = new int[2,5,6,8]; // four dimensional array, of 2x5x6x8 elements
```

See the pattern? The number of dimensions is determined by **how many numbers** you specify in the array declaration. The sizes of each dimension is determined by the **values of each number** in the declaration.

Comment: Well... like I said, probably overlooking something obvious. Doesn't help that I'm basing it on a VB project that did it the way I did, and somehow succeeded...

Thanks. I have these brain farts every now and again.

Comment: @KChaloux: Maybe you are confusing checking the lengths of jagged arrays with the lengths of dimensions in a multidimensional array?

Comment: Id add what a 3 dimensional array looks like: double[,,] x = new double[3,4,5];

Answer (score 4):

Your matrix only has 2 dimensions, both having length of 3 elements. The third `MessageBox` line is trying to print the length of a non-existent third dimension.

Answer (score 3):

Just to provide a visual example and provide an answer in my own words... (I failed at first to see why the exception was being thrown, also):

`double[,] x = new double[3, 3];` gives an array that looks like this:

```
[0,0] [1,0] [2,0]
[0,1] [1,1] [2,1]
[0,2] [1,2] [2,2]
```

I thought that the code was trying to find the length of what might be thought of as a subarray, where each row represents an array that is in turn a member of a larger array.

In actuality the rows are not themselves arrays, just members (doubles) of the original array. The `GetLength` method is looking for the dimensions of the array rather than the length (which might be confusing because `Length` is used to determine the number of members in an array). This array has two dimensions, the `X` dimension and the `Y` dimension, if you will.

Think of it like a flat sheet, which has two dimensions. If you add a third:

```
double[,,] x = new double[3, 3, 3];
```

The sheet becomes a cube, a new dimension `Z` is added, and the third `GetLength` would work.

Answer (score 1):

```
double[,,] x = new double[3, 3, 3];

MessageBox.Show(x.GetLength(0).ToString());
MessageBox.Show(x.GetLength(1).ToString());
MessageBox.Show(x.GetLength(2).ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have 3 dimensions defined in your array, so you can only get the length of two.  Your code is asking for the dimensions of a cube, not a square.

```
double[,] x = new double[3,3] // This sets up a two-dimensional array

MessageBox.Show(x.GetLength(0).ToString()); //Shows the length of the X axis
MessageBox.Show(x.GetLength(1).ToString()); //Shows the length of the Y axis
MessageBox.Show(x.GetLength(2).ToString()); //Trys to show the length of Z Axis.
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you visualize what's been explained.

Your array of x as you've declared it looks like this:

```
double[,] x = new double[3, 3];

Dimensions     0,1    0,1    0,1            
Element       [0,0], [0,1], [0,2]   
Element       [1,0], [1,1], [1,2]
Element       [2,0], [2,1], [2,2]
Lengths        3,3    3,3    3,3
```